# How do I make appDidBecomeActive show the view of rootViewController?

Tags: ios, view, viewwillappear

I have a UIImageView on top of my rootViewController (I'm using the storyboard only by the way) and I want my app, whenever it comes from sleep, to show that view on top of rootViewController.

After `application:didFinishWithLaunchOptions` that view actually appears, because it belongs to it on the storyboard, but whenever it awakes from sleep and goes to rootViewController, it never shows

I guess the `viewWillAppear` is not called, why is this?

Comment: have u tried notifying the RootViewController when the app becomes active with an UINotification?

Answer (score 3):

for doing stuff when the app becomes active, its not safe to rely on viewWillAppear or DidAppear. its best to add an observer to the rootviewcontroller for the app did become active notification.

add this on viewDidLoad of your root view controller

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(methodToShowViewOnTop)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

and make sure to implement the method

```
-(void)methodToShowViewOnTop{
                // code that puts the view on top
}
```